# C++ main header file with smaller headers error

Tags: c++

I'm rewriting a project to reorganize and improvements, and for some reason I'm getting a weird error.

I have the headers:

```
//Main.h
#include "Errors.h"
class MainClass
{
    public:
        ErrorClass errors;
};


//Errors.h
class ErrorClass
{
    public:
        MainClass* mainClassPtr;
};


//Main.cpp
#include "Main.h"

//nothing except the constructor


//Errors.cpp
#include "Main.h"

//constructor only
```

I have this exact same set up in the original project and it compiles fine, but in this new one (which has no functions yet) I get the errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

5 times (total of 10 errors).
They all point to the line 21 in *Errors.h*, which has:

```
private:
    MainClass* mainClassPtr; //line 21
```

I tried to clean and rebuild, but the error continues.

Why does this work in a project and not in this other, what am I doing wrong and how can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Errors.h, you should make what we called a *forward declaration*:

```
//Errors.h
   class MainClass;
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ The forward declaration

   class ErrorClass
   {
    public:
        MainClass* mainClassPtr;
   //   ^^^^^^^^^    It is needed for here
   };
//  ^ Don't forget the semicolon here !
```

Because you have a member which is a pointer to `MainClass` you should make a forward declaration to indicate to the compiler that this type exists.

Comment: Why does my other project this same setup works without the forward declaration? I thought by using the "Main.h" header in the .cpp file it would already get the declarations in the "Main.h" file (since it includes "Errors.h")

Comment: @Danicco it probably works by pure chance, because you include something you require indirectly via another header. You need the forward declaration.

Comment: @Danicco I think you other project should have something a little bit different to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to forward declare `MainClass` in `Errors.h`, and add a trailing `;` to the class definitions:

```
//Errors.h

class MainClass; // forward declaration

class ErrorClass
{
    public:
        MainClass* mainClassPtr;

}; // trailing ;
```

You should also add include guards to the headers.